# Optimise python while loop with try exception

Tags: python, loops, optimization, while-loop, try-catch

this is a simple question for a newbie python developer, but as I know python code can be optimised a lot ... I was wondering if there is a way to optimise the following, so I don't need 2 while loops, but I also do not want to re-ask the user to input the 1st number if he already sone that correctly:

```
def sum(a, b):
    return (a + b)

while True:
    try:
        # TODO: write code...
        a = int(input('Enter 1st number: '))
        break
    except:
        print("Only integers allowed for input!")
        continue

while True:
    try:
        # TODO: write code...
        b = int(input('Enter 2nd number: '))
        break
    except:
        print("Only integers allowed for input!")
        continue

print(f'Sum of {a} and {b} is {sum(a, b)}')
```

Comment: As your code is working, this question would be a much better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function (with a simplified loop).
You may want to rename the `sum` function as there is already a built-in function with the same name.

```py
def my_sum(a, b):
    return a + b

def get_int_from_user():
    while True:
        try:
            # TODO: write code...
            return int(input('Enter a number: '))
        except:
            print("Only integers allowed for input!")


a = get_int_from_user()
b = get_int_from_user()

print(f'Sum of {a} and {b} is {my_sum(a, b)}')
```